# Infinite "for" loop

Tags: javascript

I'm writing code on Javascript for a project breakout game, and right now I'm adding the bricks. Somehow, I've created myself an infinite loop. I *know* that this is the correct code to at least put the bricks on the screen, but the code simply won't run on my computer, it just breaks. Could someone determine where the infinite loop is created? Thanks!

```
//Brick Constants
var NUM_ROWS = 8;
var BRICK_TOP_OFFSET = 10;
var BRICK_SPACING = 2;
var NUM_BRICKS_PER_ROW = 10;
var BRICK_HEIGHT = 10;
var SPACE_FOR_BRICKS = getWidth() - (NUM_BRICKS_PER_ROW + 1) * BRICK_SPACING;
var BRICK_WIDTH = SPACE_FOR_BRICKS / NUM_BRICKS_PER_ROW;

//Paddle Constants
var PADDLE_WIDTH = 80;
var PADDLE_HEIGHT = 15;
var PADDLE_OFFSET = 10;

//Ball Constants
var BALL_RADIUS = 15;

var brick;

function start(){
    addBricks();
}

function addBricks(){
    var brickSepY = BRICK_TOP_OFFSET;
    for(var i = 0 ; i < NUM_ROWS ; i++){
        var brickSepX = BRICK_SPACING;
        for(var j = 0 ; j < NUM_BRICKS_PER_ROW ; i++){
            brick = new Rectangle(BRICK_WIDTH, BRICK_HEIGHT);
            brick.setPosition(brickSepX, brickSepY);
            add(brick);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In the inner `for` you are incrementing `i` instead of `j`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change:

```
for(var j = 0 ; j < NUM_BRICKS_PER_ROW ; i++)
//                                  here ^^^
```

to:

```
for(var j = 0 ; j < NUM_BRICKS_PER_ROW ; j++)
//                                  here ^^^
```

Comment: Haha, I'm so unaware of things! Thank you, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are increasing the **I** of the first for change for **j**

```
function addBricks(){
    var brickSepY = BRICK_TOP_OFFSET;
    for(var i = 0 ; i < NUM_ROWS ; i++){
        var brickSepX = BRICK_SPACING;
        for(var j = 0 ; j < NUM_BRICKS_PER_ROW ; **i++**){
            brick = new Rectangle(BRICK_WIDTH, BRICK_HEIGHT);
            brick.setPosition(brickSepX, brickSepY);
            add(brick);
        }
    }
}
```